# Hide rows conditionally in excel table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to be able to hide rows in a table if the first column is blank.  I need the macro to work on tables in different sheets so I search for the table name first using listobjects, I have no problem getting the table name.  I have seen how to accomplish this with a general range of cells, but not within a Table.  Any help is appreciated.

I have a similar macro to unhide rows in the table and it works fine because it simiply loops through all rows in the ListObject variable 'MyTable' and does not have the IF statement.

```
    HideBlankTableRows()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim row As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set myTable = ws.ListObjects(1)

    For Each row In myTable.DataBodyRange
       If row.Columns(1, 1).Value = "" Then     ' Error is caused by this row
           row.Hidden = True
        End If
     Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Each row In myTable.DataBodyRange` will actually loop through each cell in the body of the table, which you probably don't want. Since you're only checking the first column in each row, it would be faster to loop through each row in the table using `Each row In myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows`.

Also, <del>the `Range` object doesn't have a `Columns` property, so you'll have to</del> you can use the `Cells` property and provide the row and column number of the cell you want to reference (row 1, column 1).

The updated code would be as follows:

```
For Each row In myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows
    If row.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
       row.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Small note, `Range` _does_ have a `Columns` property.  `row.Columns(1).Value` will also work here.

Comment: right, `Columns(1)` and not `Columns(1,1)`. Will update just to show `Cells` as another option

Comment: This works flawlessly and I really like Chris's approach of using row.Columns(1).value,   It looks so simple and makes so much sense, only after seeing the right way to do it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Since you guys are so great, I would like to add a twist and add one more question.  I would like to find the last row in the table with data in the first column (I know how to find the last row when its just a range of cells). and then make the next row visible.  essentially Im hiding all blank rows but leaving the next one available.  Let me know if I should post this as a new question

Comment: I found the answer to my additional question so I thought I would share.  Just need use activecell.offsett also do a Do Until loop to skip over any hidden rows

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fix provided by JayCal, you can utilise the `ListObject` properties to reference the column by name:

```
For Each rw In myTable.ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange
    If rw.Value = vbNullString Then
        rw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

You could also use the `ListObject` `AutoFilter` method

```
myTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=lo.ListColumns("ColumnName").Index, Criteria1:="<>"
```